# Special character with latex

Tags: fontspec, characters

I'am trying to write an equation where thee is this special caracter: `\^{e}`

```
\begin{equation}
\^{e} = 1
\end{equation}
```

But the probleme is `\^{e}` is invisible, I see only “= 1”

Comment: `\^` is a text (not math) accent, you want `\hat{e}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please, make an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @KeksDose I suggested a duplicate: feel free to vote:-)